# How to enlarge a disk image created by Linux Deploy (Android) in Mac?

Tags: linux, mac, partitioning

I created a disk image with Linux Deploy and installed Debian into it.

By using `adb pull /sdcard/linux.img .`, I obtained the disk image from Android. The image size is 4.5GB. Here is the output of `fdisk` (which is weird, as it does not show any partition)

```
$ fdisk linux.img
Disk: linux.img geometry: 522/255/63 [8386560 sectors]
Signature: 0x0
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

How can I enlarge this disk image to 8GB in Mac? I have MacPorts installed, so I can use part of Linux packages, such as `resize2fs`.